# How to maximise a window across two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

It's easy to maximise windows on a single monitor (press the maximise button, or drag the window titlebar to the top of the screen).

How can I maximise a window so that it takes up two screens?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is possible by manually telling Compiz the screen output size, using the combined resolution of the two monitors. That's where the limitation kicks in: both displays need to have the same (vertical) resolution for this to make sense (else you'd end up with cut off content on the smaller screen or dead space on the bigger one).

For example, with two monitors with 1920x1080 resolution, you'd:

- Open the CompizConfig Settings Manager (if you haven't already, install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package) and go to the *General Options* plugin.
- On the *Display Settings* tab, disable the *Detect Outputs* checkbox, select the *640x480+0+0* entry and click on *Edit*,
- Now change this to *3840x1080+0+0* and hit close.

[image]

Compiz should now treat your multi-monitor setup as one big output.

Comment: That helps, thanks! However it changes the behavior of double click on any window. Ideally I would to be able to tell that this time I want a normal maximisation and this other time I prefer a double one.

Comment: I'm wondering aobut that, too. Is it possible to have this on a per-window basis?

Comment: This just treats your monitors as a single display. How about the ability to keep independent displays, and span a window across them with a shortcut? Pretty much the same way win7 does.

Comment: This also works for Chrome in kiosk mode, very nice.

Comment: Compiz/Unity will be soon deprecated. An answer for Gnome 3 is needed.

Comment: doesn't work for 18.04

Comment: doesn't seem to work on Wayland?

Answer (score 5):

Drag your window until it snaps to one edge of first monitor then resize it all the way to the other end of the secondary monitor. It is not real window maximization, but it displays window content wider or higher if monitors are positioned one above other.

Comment: If it doesn't have a keyboard shortcut, it won't be used.

Comment: @TomislavNakic-Alfirevic, actually I use this method quite often when I'm coding and need to see several source codes at the same time. I don't care a few seconds needed to use this method, since I'm gonna work in that way for some hour.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I could have made a fine point saying "most people won't use it without a shortcut" instead of flat out "won't be used", but my point was that when people manipulate windows hundreds of times a day, not having a keyboard shortcut for a particular kind of manipulation will limit the user base to a very small fraction of what it otherwise would have been because it's much less useful. Sure, I stretched windows across 2 screens, but I did it less than once a year. I would have done it more often if there was a shortcut and I believe many others would, too.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `xdotool` and setup shortcuts/scripts.

I just did a quick test on a window and in my multi-monitor environment this made a window full screen across both monitors:

`xdotool search --name "Untitled"`

`xdotool windowmove 96469240 -26 4`

`xdotool windowsize 96469240 110% 110%`

I got the -26 4 starting coordinates by putting at top-left and `xdotool getwindowgeometry 96469240`

And not sure why 100% was not stretching to actually 100% of the monitors...

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to elaborate on @codlord's great suggestion:

Mapping `xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 110% 110%` to a **keyboard shortcut** did exactly the trick (i.e., under *Settings*) - this should work regardless of the desktop manager (Gnome, Cinnamon, XFCE, etc.).

- You can quickly **first test it out on a terminal window** by entering the above command into that very terminal.
- Note that on Debian/Ubuntu systems you **may first need to install** `xdotool` via: `sudo apt install xdotool`
- The manpage `man xdotool` was very helpful and contains a lot of other neat ideas.

Comment: This is brilliant.