# Stitch two monitors together

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, twinview

I have two HD projectors that I would like to show an application in fullscreen mode across.

I am running 17.10 with an nVidia GTX570 with the latest drivers from nVidia. The projectors are recognised just fine but I am unable to get full screen windows to span across the two. I read that a feature called "Twin View" is supposed to achieve just that, but there is no such setting in the `nvidia-settings` app. I tried to set `Option   "Twin View"` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it seems to have no effect.
Is this feature still supported?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you will be able to accomplish what you want. In your case both projectors have the same resolution, so fullscreen mode would actually result in a rectangle. That is not the case if the monitors/projectors do not have the same resolution. Application would have to deal with non rectangular window. I don't think applications (or windows managers) can do that.

Probably you have one primary screen with launchbar, taskbar and everything, while other has nothing. That is already a difference, which makes screens unequal. When you maximize a window the taskbar on one screen makes the maximized windows of different dimensions. Well, fullscreen makes the same size on both but only if they have the same resolution.

Does twinview makes actually one display? Usually different monitors have different DISPLAY settings (hostname:0.0, hostname:0.1,...). If you have more X servers running than you have hostname:0.0, hostname:0.1,... for the first XServer and hostname:1.0, hostname:1.1,... for the second one and so on. So, fulscreen probably takes over one screen (:0.0 or :0.1).

Take a look here. Maybe compiz can help you:

- [How to maximise a window across two monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73573/how-to-maximise-a-window-across-two-monitors)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182182/stretch-window-over-two-monitors-with-gap-in-between
- https://superuser.com/questions/241094/how-to-fullscreen-application-across-both-monitors-of-dual-head-display