# Two monitors 1920x1080 as 3840x1080

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, intel

I'm starting using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a problem.

I'm creating project of game, which I need to be shown on resolution 3840x1080.

I've got two monitors 1920x1080, and Intel Graphic Card 
(Nvidia surround is not useful here ).

On Windows it is easy to set by using the Intel® Graphics Control Panel

I cannot see something like this in Ubuntu.

Could you please help me or tell me, on which Linux distributions this is easy to perform?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly: have you tried going to `Displays` in the settings (search "Display" in the applications menu to find it) and selecting "Join Displays"?

Comment: Yes i tried using setting but still I have two 1920x1080.
I need one 3840 x 1080.

So for example if I will open youtube, and click on fullscreen mode then I'will get youtube on two monitors.

And then I open a game I will get the same effect : )

Thank you for your answer : )

Comment: I see...  I know it's not *exactly* what you're looking for, but a possible work around would be to unmaximize your given window then resize it to cover both screens... at least that works on Unity with Ubuntu 16.04.  I don't currently have an 18.04 installation with 2 screens.

Comment: To get it to **really** work, the only way I personally know of would be to switch to the Unity desktop environment then use the information in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/94192/527350)

Comment: I'm using godot, but maybe it would works, I will try now,
Thank you : )

Comment: Eh I don't know why it dosen't work : ( Even when I try to maximie website browser I still have it only on on screen

Comment: Weird...  I'll chew on it and see if I can come up with something.  Sorry!

Comment: Wait just a sec... Just to make sure we're on the same page... did you try *Unity* or the *Unity desktop environment*?

Comment: Oh God I thought Unity as Unity3d engine,
You're right! AfterI installed unity desktop, it works
I'm so happy, so happy, you're really great!

Comment: Awesome!  So glad it worked!  I'm posting it as an answer so as to be clearer for future users.  Feel free to hit the `Accept` checkmark to show that it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution in this case was simply to switch to the Unity Desktop Environment, after which the OP was able to use the information in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/94192/527350):

- Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Go to the `Display Settings` tab and disable output detection
- Edit the `640x480+0+0` entry to read `3840x1080+0+0`
- Then close, and it should work!