# How not to maximise windows across monitors on 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, unity, multiple-monitors

For some reason Ubuntu 20.04 is maximising windows across my monitors which is really frustrating. I would like it to only maximise windows within the monitor how can I do this?

This question is the opposite of what I am looking for [How to maximise a window across two monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73573/how-to-maximise-a-window-across-two-monitors) following it I tried tweaking CompizConfig Settings Manager but I don't think I know how to do this.

This multi monitor behaviour is very frustrating and I am considering to try a couple different desktop environments.

Comment: The old answer isn't applicable to the current Ubuntu with Gnome DE. AFAIK it no longer uses Compiz so it couldn't possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

After unplugging the monitor restarting the machine and then plugging the monitor back dual monitors are not maximising the windows across both screens.